# Django: How to save database connection

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database with a table with almost 2000 rows. Client loads the first 75 rows, and when the user scrolls down the client loads another 75. My task is to optimise loading of additional data.

There are three queries to actually retrieve the data. Two of them take 50 ms each, and the other one takes 150ms, which adds up to total of 250ms, whereas the actual time Python code gets executed is 600ms. I measured execution of each query and then printed the queries. I noticed that the first query takes additional 350ms to execute, but `connection.queries` says that it took the query 50ms.

I removed the first query (substituted it with a dummy) and noticed that now the time is 550ms and the second query takes additional 350ms. I added the first query back and substituted it with raw SQL like this:

```
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        t_count_query = time.time()
        cursor.execute('...')
        result = cursor.fetchone()[0] # the result of this query is a single value
```

Instead of one line I now have `connection.cursor()` and then the actual query. I decided to time them separately with this code:

```
    t_connecting = time.time()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    t_connecting = time.time() - t_connecting
    print 'Connection time: {0}'.format(t_connecting)

    t_count_query = time.time()
    cursor.execute('...')
    result = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    t_count_query = time.time() - t_count_query
    print 'Count query: {0}'.format(t_count_query)
```

The ouput:

```
Connection time: 0.367555141449
Count query: 0.0511040687561
```

As you can see `connection.cursor()` takes about 350ms, and the query about 50ms. That also explains why the second query takes 350ms longer when the first is not present. The Django query (I mean something like `MyModel.objects.all()`) also has to connect to the database which in my case takes around 350ms.

Therefore every time the user hits an end on the client the server has to open a new connection and waste 350ms. It's ok when the user presses 'next' button to get another page of data. In that case 350ms make almost no difference. But when the client is one long scrollable page, this waiting every time the user hits an end presents an annoying user experience.

Therefore my question is, can I somehow save the connection to the database for a specified time, say like for 10 minutes, to get the scrolling on client side smoother?

**EDIT**

I googled 'django persistent connection' and I found `CONN_MAX_AGE` and set it to 300. The funny thing is that now the 50ms query takes about 100ms. And measuring it gives me 740ms! And the request is not taking more than a SECOND! After some time (about 5 minutes) the time gets to normal 600ms.

Therefore, now I have another question. How can a persistent connection be slower than default `CONN_MAX_AGE=0`? Is there some other way to establish a persistent connection and should I use it instead of setting `CONN_MAX_AGE`?

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent pagination?

Comment: No, I am not. I have a legacy pagination code. I cannot change client, and this client's pagination is annoying to users. I am trying to optimize the python code to make the client less annoying

Comment: Do you mean you have client side pagination currently? it still sounds as though you're after server side pagination, perhaps I misunderstood

Comment: Client handles pagination, it sends to the server requests with two parameters `startRow` and `endRow` server code checks the values of these parameters. If they are present the server returns rows in this range. What I want is to make server return faster, so that the client would look better. As I explained the most time expensive operation is the connection to the database. I want `django` not to extablish a new connection every time a user moves to another page

Comment: I'd suggest caching the results instead of trying to optimise querying.

Comment: I will do it. The point is that currenly the most time consuming operation is the connection to the database. Django solved this problem via `CONN_MAX_AGE` in the `settings.py`, the interesting thing is that with this parameter set responses became twice as slow, whereas I expected them to become twice as faster.

Comment: `CONN_MAX_AGE` should help you but still the connection needs to be established in the first request. For next requests you should see the difference though.

Comment: I also thought so, the funny thing is that next requests became twice as slow. That's is surprising and I have no idea how persistent connection can make queries slow

Comment: Is it always twice as slow every time you run it? Benchmarking like this can be inaccurate.

Comment: When I set the parameter and restarted the server, I made a long series of requests, at first they were twice as slow, then they went back to normal. I didn't measure total time interval before requests went back to normal, I will do it when I go back to work. I think I shall check Django source to see how persistent connection work